# Deleting a site in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, variations

I deleted a variation site (after deleting the label), at the variation root level like /fr-ca, through content and structure. There were a bunch of sites below it. It then went to the page with the green spinning wheel saying to wait for sites to get deleted. Problem is it is taking forever. The http request must probably have been cancelled cause it's shows error messages in console in dev tools. But when I check the sites, they seem to be deleted which is good.

Does anyone know if everything will be fine or do I need to do any additional steps to ensure site is fully deleted? Anything with relationships list too?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it is correct that you delete the variation site after deleting the variation label.

And to check if the variation site is deleted successfully, you could go to site settings->site collection administration->recycle bin-> click “Deleted from end user Recycle Bin” in the left navigation.